# Using Content Store in NS-3

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, ns-3

I'm  new to ns-3 and I can't figure out how to use the content store parameter when I create new scenarios in ns-3. I keep changing the size but doesn't seem to change much in the results. Any ideas on how should I use the content store efficiently?

```
 ndn::StackHelper ndnHelper;
  ndnHelper.SetOldContentStore("ns3::ndn::cs::Lru", "MaxSize", "100");
  ndnHelper.InstallAll()
```

Comment: Actually including your source code would help quite a bit to figure out what the problem might be

Comment: the actual maxsize here is the "buffer" for every node?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change CS size with

```
Config::Set ("/NodeList/0/$ns3::ndn::ContentStore/MaxSize", UintegerValue (1)); // number after nodeList is global ID of the node (= node->GetId ())
Config::Set ("/NodeList/1/$ns3::ndn::ContentStore/MaxSize", UintegerValue (2));
Config::Set ("/NodeList/2/$ns3::ndn::ContentStore/MaxSize", UintegerValue (200));
```

Source: http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/pipermail/ndnsim/2013-February/000080.html